# Taylor expansion of $g(X_n)$ (probability theory)

Tags: probability

I am reading up the proof and there is a part that I don't understand.

Assumption: Let $X_n$ be random variable such that $\sqrt{n}(X_n-\mu)\to N(0,\sigma^2)$ in distribution sense. $g(x)$ is differentiable function whose derivative does not vanish.

Question: In the proof, the author states that we have a Taylor's expansion $g(X_n)=g(\mu)+g'((\mu)(X_n)-\mu)+o_p(|X_n-\mu|)$ where $A_n=o_p(|B_n|)$ means that $\dfrac {A_n} {B_n}\to 0$ in a probability sense.
I'm not sure how the part where degrees are greater than or equal to 2 can be expressed as such. It seems to me that $P(|X_n-\mu|>\epsilon)$ does not necessarily converges to $0$. Could someone give me any insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is delta-method, see, eg. [www.stat.rice.edu/~dobelman/notes_papers/math/TaylorAppDeltaMethod.pdf](http://www.stat.rice.edu/%7Edobelman/notes_papers/math/TaylorAppDeltaMethod.pdf)
page 4

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It's indeed a part of delta method, but the exposition in the link is still unclear to me to address my question

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out so I might just post the idea

Because if $X_n\to X$ and $Y_n\to Y$ in probability then $X_n+Y_n\to X+Y$ in probability, it boils down to showing that $|X_n-\mu|\to 0$ in probability. Indeed this follows from the condition that $X_n$ satisfies central limit theorem property, because $P(X_n-\mu\leq \frac{x}{\sqrt{n}})-P(X_n-\mu\leq \frac{-x}{\sqrt{n}})=P(|X_n-\mu|<\frac x{\sqrt{n}})$ and so on.